# Where Azure Log Analytics store the data

Tags: azure-storage, azure-log-analytics

I started to study Azure Log Analytics and I'm wondering a very simple question: where are stored the data?
Is there a kind of database behind this resource? How can I access that?
If not, is there a way to "redirect" the logs into a particular storage?

I didn't find any info on the documentations.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Azure Diagnostics is an Azure extension that enables you to collect diagnostic data from a worker role, web role, or virtual machine running in Azure. The data is stored in an Azure storage account (you have to assign a diagnostic storage account to store log data) and can then be collected by Log Analytics.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really helpfull, but I have to investigate a little bit more because this component is more complex then expected and I still have some questions.
For example: I tried to attach a storage account log to the "Log Analytics" component and I've the following options:"IIS Logs","Events","Syslog (Linux)","ETW Logs","Service Fabric Events". I tried to log an event but seems it doesn't appear in the storage. Can you suggest a good totorial to achive that? Thanks